# Function did not count a sum

Tags: javascript, function

I have two functions. First function works only if you click on the button "demo", and second must work WHEN you click on button to count variable "c". But it didnt work correct. Why?

What i need to change in code what it works correct? What i do wrong and how i can do better my code. Give some solves plz.

**P.S.:** correct - it is when you click on the button and just then function aaa() must work and get var "c" with value = 7;

```
<a id="demo" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').onclick()">Button</a>

document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function() {
    a = 5;
    document.getElementById('demo').onclick.called=true;
    alert(a);
    return a;
}

function aaa() {
    if(document.getElementById('demo').onclick.called) {
        c = document.getElementById('demo').onclick() + 2;
        alert(c);
        return c;
    } else {
        alert("no function");
    }
}

aaa();
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this result? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Psylene/cx5z548p/)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is your code is not calling `aaa()` on click of `button`. The alert that you are getting is of event listener.

You can try following code:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function demoClick() {
  a = 5;
  document.getElementById('demo').onclick.called = true;
  alert("Not aaa: " + a);
  return a;
}

function aaa() {
  if (document.getElementById('demo').onclick.called) {
    c = document.getElementById('demo').onclick() + 2;
    alert("aaa: " + c);
    return c;
  } else {
    alert("no function");
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="demo">Button</a>
<button onclick="aaa()">Check Sum</button>
```

Also, if you are doing this:

```
document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function()
```

You do not need this:

```
<a id="demo" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').onclick()">Button</a>
             ^^^^^^^
```

#### Edit 1

You can try something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ckferf03/).

Note: If you add more than 1 event listeners to an element, there is no sure way of determining, which one will execute first.

#### Idea Approach

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ckferf03/1/)

```js
function aaa() {
  if (document.getElementById('demo').onclick.called) {
    var c = getValue() + 2;
    alert("Updated Value (Sum): " + c);
    return c;
  } else {
    alert("no function");
    updateState();
  }
}

function getValue() {
  var a = 5;
  alert("Base Value: " + a);
  return a;
}

function updateState(){
 document.getElementById('demo').onclick.called = true;
}

function registerEvents(){
 document.getElementById("demo").onclick = aaa;
}

registerEvents();
```

```html
<a id="demo">Button</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is a little bit what i need. It give me an answer what i need, but can somehow do it without second button "Check Sum"? What summ was automaticaly get, when i click on the button with id="demo" "Button" ?

Comment: So you want 2 event listeners on same button and want to pass values among them. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @DeniWassulmaier I have updated my answer. Kindly check.

Comment: Rajesh! Your first code was something wright what i need, but at first i see the solve of my problem - code, in which i get total sum(5+2) when i click on the button "Button". Code must count total sum autimatically, after i click on Button with variable a =5;, and not count after i click on one button and then on another.  I save your first code with two buttons, but is it possible to do like this - automatically counting?

Comment: Have you seen solution under `Ideal Approach`?

Comment: i saw your code. Plz see this. https://jsfiddle.net/wassulmaier/by1f9b6f/1/    . If i click on "demo" i saw result of "a" and "b" and "total sum". How can change this code, if i click only on button a , than get result from "a" , than result of "total sum" equal "a", if i click only on button b , than get result from "b" -  and if i clock on both buttons - "total sum" will be sum of this events? I cant do it Rajesh. Help.

Comment: @DeniWassulmaier check the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/by1f9b6f/2/). Updates, added `updateUIState` function and called it inside `else` and updated `if` condition from `=true` to `=== true`

Comment: In update fiddle code works like this: 1) i click on the button and get alert(no function); 2) the new alert(not aaa=5) 3 alert(aaa=7). But my problem is not in this. I have a calculation and 2 calculation options. If i need first option("a") then total sum must equal "5", if i need second option, than total sum need to equal "2". If i need first and then second options - Total Sum mest plus a to b and get the sum.  You give a near right solution earlier. But i have a two options, like in my last fiddle.

Comment: Sorry updeted fiddle is not solution what i need. I have a calculation and 2 calculation options. If i need first option("a") then total sum must equal "5", if i need second option, than total sum need to equal "2". If i need first and then second options - Total Sum mest plus a to b and get the sum. You give a near right solution earlier. But i have a two options, like in my last fiddle.

Comment: @DeniWassulmaier Sorry, but I do not understand the problem statement itself. You should update question with proper explanation and someone will help you.